# Ubuntu (20.04, 22.04.18.04) doesn't detect SATA SSD DISK on HPE Apollo 6500 while installing OS

Tags: hp, disk, sssd

Ubuntu (20.04, 22.04.18.04)  doesn't detect SATA SSD DISK on HPE Apollo 6500 server while installing OS. I tried from HPE ILO and USB drive but OS installation started and after some time it ended with the error "Guided storage configuration Block probing did not discover any disks. Unfortunately this means that installation will not be possible"

However, Redhat and CentOS could detect the DISK. I tried everything and also took support from HPE . HPE responded it is some driver issue with Ubuntu.

[Error while installing OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOx3C.png)

Comment: Are you using the server version? And best to only use 22.04 LTS unless that is an old system where  drivers have been discontinued and then older version of Ubuntu may be better.

Comment: Yes I used server version of Ubuntu 22.04, 20.04 and 18.04 downloaded from their official website.